# Are there shorter Mongo shell commands?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

In the mongo prompt typing `show collections;` is tedious, even with autocomplete. Postgres prompt commands are so much snappier. Are there any shortcuts in the Mongo shell?

Comment: Postgres prompt commands are also so much harder to memorize. And no, I don't know of shorter versions.

Comment: You could use a GUI application for Mongo. That will show all collections in a list view.